# Converting int arrays to string arrays in numpy without truncation

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

Trying to convert int arrays to string arrays in numpy

```
In [66]: a=array([0,33,4444522])
In [67]: a.astype(str)
Out[67]: 
array(['0', '3', '4'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Not what I intended

```
In [68]: a.astype('S10')
Out[68]: 
array(['0', '33', '4444522'], 
      dtype='|S10')
```

This works but I had to know 10 was big enough to hold my longest string. Is there a way of doing this easily without knowing ahead of time what size string you need? It seems a little dangerous that it just quietly truncates your string without throwing an error.

Comment: For visitors from 2018 and beyond: `a.astype(str)` will now work exactly as desired.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Again, this can be solved in pure Python:

```
>>> map(str, [0,33,4444522])
['0', '33', '4444522']
```

Or if you need to convert back and forth:

```
>>> a = np.array([0,33,4444522])
>>> np.array(map(str, a))
array(['0', '33', '4444522'], 
      dtype='|S7')
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I need to become more acquainted with map.

Comment: `list(map(str, [0,33,4444522]))`

Answer (score 56):

You can stay in numpy, doing

```
np.char.mod('%d', a)
```

This is twice faster than `map` or list comprehensions for 10 elements, four times faster for 100. This and other string operations are documented [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.char.html).

Comment: Cool, but I can't find documentation for this, could you provide a link if possible?

Comment: @MikhailV Sure, just added a link to the answer.

Answer (score 18):

Use `arr.astype(str)`, as `int` to `str` conversion is now supported by `numpy` with the desired outcome:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0,33,4444522])

res = a.astype(str)

print(res)

array(['0', '33', '4444522'], 
      dtype='<U11')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find the smallest sufficient width like so:

```
In [3]: max(len(str(x)) for x in [0,33,4444522])
Out[3]: 7
```

Alternatively, just construct the `ndarray` from a list of strings:

```
In [7]: np.array([str(x) for x in [0,33,4444522]])
Out[7]: 
array(['0', '33', '4444522'], 
      dtype='|S7')
```

or, using `map()`:

```
In [8]: np.array(map(str, [0,33,4444522]))
Out[8]: 
array(['0', '33', '4444522'], 
      dtype='|S7')
```

Comment: For large arrays, `map()` is a better option than a list comprehension because it pushes the execution of the code into C.

Comment: @JoelCornett Sometimes `map` can be slightly faster (in this example it's about 3% faster than using a list comprehension for me), but this isn't always the case, and list comprehensions are considered more pythonic. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1247490/1191119

Comment: @jorgeca: Absolutely, it isn't always the case. Incidentally, as I was doing the research, I came upon [this enlightening article](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str.html) by Guido.

Comment: @JoelCornett Definitely, that's a great read. I knew it but it's well worth revisiting.

Comment: @jorgeca the article seems to have moved/evaporated - any idea where it is now? I couldn't find it in [this list of essays](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/), nor searching list2str on python.org...

Comment: @drevicko here's an [updated link](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/)

Answer (score 0):

`np.apply_along_axis(lambda y: [str(i) for i in y], 0, x)`

Example

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> x = np.array([-1]*10+[0]*10+[1]*10)
array([-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1])

>>> np.apply_along_axis(lambda y: [str(i) for i in y], 0, x).tolist()
['-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '0', '0',
 '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1',
 '1', '1', '1', '1']
```

Answer (score 0):

For those working with Python 3.9, the command should be:

```
list(map(str, [1,2,3]))
```