# Weird behavior of numpy array type setting

Tags: python, numpy

The code

```
np.array([100,200,300],dtype=str)
```

returns:

```
array(['1', '2', '3'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) says:

> dtype : data-type, optional
>
> The desired data-type for the array. If not given, then the type will be determined
>   as the minimum type required to hold the objects in
>   the sequence.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Can you try using `dtype='|S3'` and see if that gives what you expect?

Comment: This question has been asked fairly recently, although I cannot find it right off. A detailed search of the `numpy` tag should lead you to it.

Comment: @SethMMorton Using `'|S3'` works

Comment: What happens if you have `np.array([101,201,301],dtype=str)` instead?

Comment: @SethMMorton Still returns the "erroneous" results.

Comment: @Ophion for future reference, I think this is the question you were referring to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958846/converting-int-arrays-to-string-arrays-in-numpy-without-truncation

Comment: @Bitwise That may be it, but I believe there is question with this exact same problem within the last month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still cannot find the question, but to get around it:

```
>>> a=[100,200,300]

>>> np.char.mod('%d', a)
array(['100', '200', '300'],
      dtype='|S3')
```

This circumvents your problem:

```
>>> a=[100,200,3005]
>>> np.char.mod('%d', a)
array(['100', '200', '3005'],
      dtype='|S4')
```

The obscure [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.mod.html), it should be noted that this is roughly 4 times slower then choosing `dtype="S.."`, but non-linearly faster then using `np.array(map(str,a))` methods.

You can also do some neat things:

```
>>> a
[1234.5, 123.4, 12345]

>>> np.char.mod('%s',a)
array(['1234.5', '123.4', '12345.0'],
      dtype='|S7')

>>> np.char.mod('%f',a)
array(['1234.500000', '123.400000', '12345.000000'],
      dtype='|S12')

>>> np.char.mod('%d',a) #Note the truncation of decimals here.
array(['1234', '123', '12345'],
      dtype='|S5')

>>> np.char.mod('%s.stuff',a)
array(['1234.5.stuff', '123.4.stuff', '12345.0.stuff'],
      dtype='|S13')
```

Additional information can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations).

Comment: Thanks! Can you add a link to the documentation for this function?

Comment: I also updated this with a few extra examples, depending on what you are doing `%d` might not be optimal for you.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see this behavior is that you have to specify the size of each string element e.g. using:

```
>>> np.array([100,200,300],dtype='S3')
      array(['100', '200', '300'], 
             dtype='|S3')
```

Otherwise the size of each element string will default to 1.

More info here:
[Numpy converting array from float to strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365520/numpy-converting-array-from-float-to-strings)

Comment: The problem is that to do this for an arbitrary list of numbers I need to check the lengths of all the numbers first.