# How to add + sign to every element in np.array

Tags: python, numpy

How to add + sign to ids which were generated by np.arange(len(web))

Comment: You need to convert them to strings if you want to concatenate a string to them.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958846/converting-int-arrays-to-string-arrays-in-numpy-without-truncation for how to convert it to a string array.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your array to strings. Then use `map()` to convert them to strings and add `+`, and convert this to an array.

```
r = np.arange(len(web))
rplus = np.array(map(lambda x: '+' + str(x), r)
```